# Prisma : select on many to many with multiple conditions

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

I have two tables `User` and `Post` that are linked by a custom many to many table such as :

```
model User {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  enabled       Bool
  posts         users_to_posts[]
}

model Post {
  id            Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  name          String
  enabled       Bool
  users         users_to_posts[]
}

model user_to_post {
  user          user? @relation(fields: [user_id], references: [id])
  user_id       Int
  post          post? @relation(fields: [post_id], references: [id])
  post_id       Int
  @@id([user_id, post_id])
}
```

I am attempting to get a list of users based on a list of post Ids where the users and the posts must be enabled.

So far I can get the right users that are enabled if they have a post that is in the given post array but I cannot check if the post is enabled or not nor can I filter the posts ( I get all of the posts associated with the user if there is a match )

Here is the ( almost ) working code I have :

```
import { PrismaClient, Prisma } from '@prisma/client'

const prisma = new PrismaClient()

export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (req.method !== 'POST') {
        res.status(400).send({ message: 'Only POST requests allowed for this route' })
    } else {
        const { posts_id } = req.query
        const posts_array = posts_id.split(",").map(function(item) {
            return parseInt(item)
        })
        const ret = await prisma.user.findMany({
            where: {
                enabled: true,
                post: { some: { post_id: { in: posts_array } }, },
            },
            include: {
                _count: { select: { post: true } }
                post: { select: { post: true }, },
            },
        })
        res.status(200).send(ret)
        // ...
    }
}
```

I am still battling to understand how I can multiple embedded selections without having to rely on typescript to get the query working properly ( witch is far from ideal )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I understand, there's 2 constraints that you need which isn't represented in your query right now.

1. Only return a `user` if the post inside `posts_array` is enabled.
2. Filter the returned posts of a `user` so that it only contains `enabled` posts.

I've updated your query to add these two conditions.

```js
const users = await prisma.user.findMany({
    where: {
        enabled: true,
        posts: {
            some: {
                post_id: { in: posts_array },
                post: {  
                    enabled: true  // for constraint 1 (only check/match against the post_ids in post array which are enabled)
                }
            },
        },

    },

    include: {
        _count: { select: { posts: true } },
        posts: {
            select: { post: true },
            where: {
                post: {  
                    enabled: true   // for constraint 2 (only include the posts which are enabled)
                }
            }
        },
    },
})
```

Keep in mind that `users[SOME_IDX]._count.posts` will contain the count of ALL the posts of that user (including those which are `disabled`). If you want the count of enabled posts only, you will have to check the length of the `users[SOME_IDX].posts` array.

By the way, based on your schema, the `user_to_post` table is somewhat redundant. You could use an [implicit many-to-many](https://www.prisma.io/docs/concepts/components/prisma-schema/relations/many-to-many-relations#implicit-many-to-many-relations) to model the relation between post and user.